# Register a WCF Service with Oracle Advanced Queueing Notification11g

Tags: wcf, oracle, notifications

I have written a WCF service that when invoked will dequeue items in an Oracle database. Is it possible to register a c#.Net WCF service to be notified when an item is enqueued?

From the documentation (specifically related to 9i) I know it's possible to register for an HTTP servlet (Documentation Found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a88890/adq08qap6.htm))

```
sys.aq$_reg_info('WS.WS_BOOKEDORDERS_QUE:BOOKED_ORDERS', 
                      DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ, 
                      'http://xyz.oracle.com/servlets/NotifyServlet', 
                        HEXTORAW('FF'));
```

but I've yet to find anything on WCF and registering notifications?